# Mat menu is displayed outside

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I need some help. I have a nav-bar and I want my username to be shown on a button and when you click that, a dropdown with multiple actions should appear. I saw in angulars documentation that this is not hard to do, but I have a problem when the dropdown is displayed.

[image]

As it can be seen, when I press the "menu" button, the Items are on the left side of the page under my page container. Here is my code:

```
  <nav
    class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3"
  >
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">What's up doc?</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target=".navbar-collapse"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded"
        (click)="toggle()"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div
        class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-end"
        [ngClass]="{ show: isExpanded }"
      >
        <ul *ngIf="userInfo" class="navbar-nav flex-grow">
          <li
            class="nav-item"
            [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
          >
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" [routerLink]="['/counter']"
              >Counter</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" [routerLink]="['/fetch-data']"
              >Fetch data</a
            >
          </li>
          <div *ngIf="userInfo" class="user-section-holder">
            
            <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
              <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
              </mat-menu> 
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```